# How to add library from submodule to project in Eclipse

Tags: c, git, eclipse, egit

I use Eclipse with egit
I have a git repo (let's say xxx) with one xxx.h file and one xxx.c file, and wanna use this repo as a submodule inside my project
So I added this submodule in Git Repositories window. Now I have folder xxx in my local repository, near the project folder
I added path to this folder in paths in my projects properties, so now I can compile project with `#include "xxx.h"` in main.h

But I:

1. can't see folder xxx in Project Explorer
2. can't jump to function body, when press F3 on function name (like Eclipse know nothing about xxx.c)
   How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refresh on projects?

Comment: Yes also I did Rebuild in C/C++ Index menu
Still doesn't work

Comment: @V4_dlm Refresh. not rebuild. Press ```F5```or right click your project and select refresh

Comment: I said, yes in answer to your previous question:)
I did it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on project name Indexer->Rebuild or Freshen new files